# Running Python on Android in ADB Shell

Tags: android, python, shell

I have a python script (2.7, but I can make Python 3 work) that is a part of a bigger testing framework, that I'd like to be able to run on Android.

I know there are various projects for creating applications based on Python, that's not what I'm interested in. I'm interested in the simplest way to make the python command line executable available for running on the Android platform I'm connected to via adb shell. So the workflow I'm aiming at is something like this:

```
<host>       $ adb shell
<and. device>$ <path1>/python <path2>/script.py <arguments>
```

I know CrystaX NDK offers a python environment but it consistently crashes with memory errors when the script ends.

Comment: Crash on exit is known issue in CrystaX NDK - https://tracker.crystax.net/issues/1108. This is caused by the fact that Google's libc (starting from Android 6.0) close stdin/stdout/stderr on exit, and that calls code defined in libcrystax.so, where whole stdio is implemented on our own and is not binary compatible with Google's one. However, this doesn't affect anything, except of the fact the application is crashed on exit. In fact, our Python build is very stable and works just fine - this is verified by our regular automated testing.

Comment: We're going to fix bug #1108 soon, completely replacing libc by libcrystax and avoiding any potential binary incompatibilities in the future, but right now it's not yet completed.

Comment: Cool. If this is a known bug that affects nothing but the error return code maybe I can just use it as is.